# upgrade to Windows 10 and simultaneously wipe the entire disk

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

I'm using Windows 8.1 and I finally realized that it's good idea for me to upgrade to Windows 10.

As far as I know, my computer is flooded with many unnecessary files etc, and I also hope its virus free but, if its not then I would like to upgrade and so during the upgrade I don't want to keep any files on the disk.

I have not started the upgrade yet but is there a way of doing something like upgrade and wipe the disk?

I'm using an antivirus but you never know.

Comment: Launch the installer from within Windows, when asked to what you want to  keep, select "Keep Nothing".  This will format your HDD and install Windows 10 on it.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed with the upgrade and let it finish.

Then you want to `Reset` Windows 10.

1. Navigate to Settings.  You can get there by clicking the gear icon on the Start menu.
2. Select "Update & security"
3. Click Recovery in the left pane.
4. Click Get started under Reset this PC
5. Click "Remove everything"
6. Select "Remove files and clean the drive"
7. Click Next
8. Click Reset when prompted
9. Click Continue when prompted.

That's it.  Your computer will reboot with a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Windows 10 upgrade and copy the installer to a USB. Booting from the USB will allow you to do a fresh installation.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10